# sharing alternatives similar to addthis/sharethis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharethis

Please have a look at http://500px.com/photo/3977429?from=popular. Down in the right corner, theres a sharing box. It looks pretty similar to sharethis. But, afaik, sharethis doesnt have embed or submit for example, and im looking for those options. Does anyone know which plugin is used here? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspecting the source leads me to believe that it is custom work. The images, links and such are placed in the HTML serverside. Only the stumbleupon is pulled from stumbleupon itself. But also not trough some third party service like sharethis.

Comment: Yea i guess so. The thing that made me unsure was that it looks very similar to sharethis...

Answer (score 7):

On the page you linked to, they didn't use anything like sharethis or addthis - they rolled their own.  Looking at the code, its clear that they went to facebook, got the facebook like button, embedded it - then wen to google, got the google plus button, etc... and made a grid of them.

You can stylize the sharethis buttons with css to pretty much any extent, 
or you can add a grid like that of your own.

The available alternatives to sharethis.com are :

- addthis.com
- addtoany.com
- socialmarker.com

I'm sure there a a lot more out there, but those seem to be the most popular.

If you want something custom like they have and want access to the buttons
here are some sets of images you may be able to use:

http://speckyboy.com/2009/01/26/30-amazingly-creative-social-bookmarks-icon-sets/